# Macbook Air (Yosemite) crashes while watching videos

Tags: video, crash, kernel-panic

For about a week now, my Macbook (Air early 2014) has been crashing whenever I have been using it to watch videos online (Youtube etc.)

I took a look at the event logs and found a number of kernel panic entries which I believe are pointing to the integrated graphics card/drivers.

Could someone confirm this, and possibly give a solution for the problem?

```
Anonymous UUID:       5A42BC33-FFCE-627D-57EF-BFD301CFFC70

Sat Jul 18 17:12:17 20    15

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff801ac17cc2): Kernel trap at 0x0000000000000200, type 14=page fault, registe    rs:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000000000200, CR3: 0x000000002170e001, CR4: 0x0000000000162    7e0
RAX: 0xffffff803811f000, RBX: 0xffffff803367e000, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x7fffffffffffffff
RSP: 0xffffff80b5013b78, RBP: 0xffffff80b5013bc0, RSI: 0x0000000000000002, RDI: 0xffffff8037bab400
R8:  0x00000000000002ab, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0xffffff8034b62000
R12: 0xffffff801b312f48, R13: 0xffffff801b229750, R14: 0xffffff8037bab400, R15: 0xffffff802cabb280
RFL: 0x0000000000010282, RIP: 0x0000000000000200, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000200, Error code: 0x0000000000000010, Fault CPU:         0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return     Address
0xffffff80b5013820 : 0xffffff801ab2bda1 
0xffffff80b50138a0 : 0xffffff801ac17c    c2 
0xffffff80b5013a60 : 0xffffff801ac34b73 
0xffffff80b5013a80 : 0x    200 
0xffffff80b5013bc0 : 0xffffff7f9cb7ca    68 
0xffffff80b5013c00 : 0xffffff7f9cb8bb95 
0xffffff80b5013c30 : 0xffffff7f9cb7d479 
0xffffff80b5013c50 : 0xffffff7f9cbe26    f8 
0xffffff80b5013c70 : 0xffffff7f9cb7d2dc 
0xffffff80b5013ca0 : 0xffffff7f9cb8b6a1 
0xffffff80b5013d00 : 0xffffff801b0b6eb1 
0xffffff80b5013d50 : 0xffffff801b0fe5b5 
0xffffff80b5013dc0 : 0xffffff801abe26    be 
0xffffff80b5013e10 : 0xffffff801ab3000c 
0xffffff80b5013e40 : 0xffffff801ab149f3 
0xffffff80b5013e90 : 0xffffff801ab2531d 
0xffffff80b5013f10 : 0xffffff801ac031ea 
0xffffff80b5013fb0 : 0xffffff801ac35396 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(156.16)[8DA5CE1F-2C00-3CE3-8BF1-1FC07BFCF4E7]@0xffffff7f9cb61000->0xffffff7f9cbcffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D8F585E8-2EE9-3135-8E37-A034123FE45C]@0xffffff7f9b324000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6F7F093D-DBEA-356A-9A08-D8EAC7F767DE]@0xffffff7f9bc62000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics(10.0.6)[3DD992A1-946D-3C47-AA58-2927ED68AF7B]@0xffffff7f9cbde000->0xffffff7f9cc3dfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(97.4)[A4AE35B7-0C17-38F2-AD0D-A4C4B40196FB]@0xffffff7f9bb3a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[D8F585E8-2EE9-3135-8E37-A034123FE45C]@0xffffff7f9b324000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[6F7F093D-DBEA-356A-9A08-D8EAC7F767DE]@0xffffff7f9bc62000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(156.16)[8DA5CE1F-2C00-3CE3-8BF1-1FC07BFCF4E7]@0xffffff7f9cb61    000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: com.apple.Web    Kit

Mac OS version:
14    E46

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: E3C26B2F-8B97-3F1D-B193-690F7E34F830
Kernel slide:     0x000000001a800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801aa00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801a900000
System model name: MacBookAir6,2 (Mac-7DF21CB3ED6977    E5)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 14180651633679
last loaded kext at 3228036860586: com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124 (addr 0xffffff7f9d1e3000, size 20480)
last unloaded kext at 132395675685: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  2.0.57 (addr 0xffffff7f9cb3e000, size 36864)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.2.0d4
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.5f8
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.5f8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.36.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 67
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.5f8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.5f8
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.24
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.16
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    41.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  264.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  41.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    2.0.57
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 2.0.57
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 2.0.57
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 397
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

System Profile:
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.5f8 15969, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638454455302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638454455302D474E2D4620
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB
Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B19, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.13f15
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **is not** a problem with the GPU. The report says, this was an issue with:

```
com.apple.WebKit
```

`WebKit` is the "software" Safari uses to render / draw the webpage.

---

This seems to be a problem originating in the OS X graphics frameworks meaning this a software problem. This could be a bug in Safari or something might be causing it.

I recommend using another browser and seeing if this happens. If it happens in another browser, it could be a problem with OS X and you might need to take a few more steps.

If it only happens in Safari, I recommend disabling all extensions to see if one of these is causing the problem.

---

From what I can tell, while WebKit was drawing the image, something "clogged" the process. That means it's probably an extension.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I had reached the conclusion that it was a driver problem due to the backtrace. I hadn't considered the application that was calling the driver. Chrome does not seem to be having the same problem thus far, so I think I'll just stick with it for now.

Answer (score 1):

That log does not show problems with the GPU.

The problems come from the Browser you are using (Safari).

First try watching without headphones plugged in.

Next, try using different browser (Firefox, Chrome...)

To verify the GPU is fine, play a video that you downloaded (from your Hard-drive).

If above is correct, lets fix your Safari or stay with another browser choice